# Blackberry Code Signing and OTA distribution

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, eclipse-plugin, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, codesign

I have a Blackberry project developed in Eclipse using the Blackberry Plugin for Eclipse.  The app works 100% fine in the simulators.

I have a signing key set from Blackberry, and I can sign the application package fine (it goes off and does 70 odd signings with Blackberry, I get back no errors).

However, when I try and use the OTA files in deliverables/Web/4.6.1/ I get the following error on the Blackberry device:

```
Error starting My_App:
Module
‘My_App’
Attempts to 
Access a secure API.
```

Which is a bit surprising since as far as I am concerned, I am signing the app!

I did notice that the code signing tool references the .cod file in deliverables/Standard/4.6.1/ and nowhere mentions the Web/ directory, so what am I doing wrong? I cannot see any settings to force Eclipse or the Blackberry plugin to sign the Web/ set of files, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `deliverables/Standard/4.6.1/` instead?

Answer (score -1):

You got this error because your app is not signed by blackberry. See: http://blog.crowe.co.nz/blog/archive/2007/07/11/BlackBerry-Code-Signing-101.aspx

Comment: *sigh* please read the question - I have keys, I was doing the signing, the web deliverables were not getting signed.  Giving me a link to a signing 101 when its patently obvious that I know the code needs to be signed and have gone to the effort of obtaining keys and installing them, and Im already doing signing isn't at all helpful.